# Laravel, having a custom controller method with custom policy method?

Tags: laravel, controller, resources, policies

I have a resource controller and want to add an extra custom policy method for destroyMany
In which I would check if the user is admin before deleting many.

The default methods work fine

| Controller Method | Policy Method |
| --- | --- |
| index | viewAny |
| show | view |
| create | create |
| store | create |
| edit | update |
| update | update |
| destroy | delete |
| destroyMany | destroyMany |

Controller destroyMany method is called, the policy isn't
Or should I stick to Gates for this extra method?
The docs say I can have any name for the methods and policies, How can both be linked?

destroyMany->destroyMany  or
destroyMany->deleteMany would be a good setup.

And would be a great addition to my resource controller (where it should reside)

```
class ResourceController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth:api');
      $this->authorizeResource(Resource::class, 'resource');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        return ResourceCollection::collection(Resource::all());
    }

    public function destroyMany(Request $request)
    {
        // gets called but needs a policy which isn't called
    }
}
```

policy

```
class ResourcePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        // works
        return $user->hasAnyRoles(['admin', 'superAdmin']);
    }

    public function delete(User $user, Resource $resource)
    {
       // works
        return $user->hasAnyRoles(['admin', 'superAdmin']);
    }

    public function deleteMany(User $user, Resource $resource)
    {
        // not called because the controller method needs to be hooked up, like the other methods
       
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Please can you also show your controller code.

Comment: I've edited my question, it's a normal resource controller with policies. Laravel 8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the addition policy method to work you will need to update the `resourceAbilityMap` for the controller. Adding the following to your controller should do the trick:

```
protected function resourceAbilityMap()
{
    return array_merge(parent::resourceAbilityMap(), [
        'destroyMany' => 'deleteMany'
    ]);
}
```

Also, if you don't return anything from your `deleteMany` policy method it will result in a 403.

If your route/controller method isn't receiving an instance of the model then you will also need to update the array returned from the `resourceMethodsWithoutModels` method:

```
protected function resourceMethodsWithoutModels()
{
    return array_merge(parent::resourceMethodsWithoutModels(), ['destroyMany']);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Although the 'destroyMany' => 'deleteMany' is added and returned via resourceAbilityMap I still get a 403, I've edited the code sample and added the delete method which works. the deleteMany has the same construction.

Comment: @user14409370 If you don't return anything from the policy method you will get a 403 since returning nothing will result in a falsy value. Sorry, I should have mentioned.

Comment: Still a 403 when returning true in the policy for deleteMany i'm afraid,... your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @user14409370 Sorry, it hadn't occurred to me that you wouldn't be passing an instance of `Resource` to the route/controller. I've updated the answer to show you'll need to add the `resourceMethodsWithoutModels` method to your controller as well.

Comment: Brilliant!  resourceMethodsWithoutModels did the trick!  I'm very grateful for your help, you show deep knowledge! Hope you get plenty bonus points. ;-)

Comment: @user14409370 Glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

A different approach is extending the policy ability and call it explicitely: a bit more tedious (you have to manually invoke `authorize` within your Controller's method) but the given ability is accessible also in other places (e.g. Blade templates, services, wherever you can use a `can` helper...).

In `AuthServiceProvider`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

public function boot(): void
{
  Gate::define('destroyMany', [ResourcePolicy::class, 'deleteMany']);
}
```

In `ResourceController`

```
public function destroyMany(Request $request)
{
  $this->authorize('destroyMany');
  // ...
}
```

Anywhere

```
$user->can('destroyMany');
```

Source: [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#writing-gates).