# Adding custom function to Policy

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a custom function for my Policy but I don't know how to use it in the route as middleware or something. Basically below is the code for my policy

```
class DepartmentPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;    

    public function list(User $user, Department $department)
    {
        return true;        
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this in my Route something like this

```
Route::prefix('/departments')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/list', [App\Http\Controllers\DepartmentController::class, 'list'])
           ->middleware('can:list,department');
});
```

But I always get a 403 function. When I remove this middleware I can access the url. But with this I get a 403.

Note: I already created the policies in the AuthServiceProvider like below

```
protected $policies = [
    '\App\Models\User'               => 'App\Policies\UserPolicy',
    '\App\Models\Department'         => 'App\Policies\DepartmentPolicy',
];
```

Can anyone tell me how to use this custom function in my custom route? Basically I know that by default if I access the `index` in the controller it will call the `viewAny` function in my DepartmentPolicy but what about the custom function in the policy and the custom route? how can I call that or link each other?

Comment: You want to do this by middleware? You can check directly in controller by Gate facade

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66544218/3584881), if its helpful

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi thanks for the reply. I tried this but didn't work